# Find out which user commented or reacted to a post on your feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am looking at the Facebook Graph API docs, specifically for

```
/{post-id}/comments
/{post-id}/reacts
/{post-id}/likes
```

I am trying to figure out if I can determine which user commented/reacted/liked a post that I posted on my wall/feed.

According to these docs, I can't figure out if this is possible? does anyone know?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/object/comments
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/object/likes
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/object/reactions

*if it's not clear*...all I really want to do here is get the user-id of the user that liked/commented on/shared/reacted to, a post that I posted (I being the logged in user to the graph api).

Comment: what for exactly? what´s the use case for this?

Comment: I am trying to determine which friends/followers on fb I haven't engaged with recently. Maybe there is a better way to do that other than looking at likes/reacts/comments on posts, but this is the only way I can think of doing it atm.

Comment: it matters because some stuff is not allowed on facebook (in that case, i see no problem though). anyway, did you try it? you can easily test api calls in the api explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: there´s a general rule though: no user data (not even the id) without specific user authorization of each user, for privacy reasons.

Comment: @ luschn ahh thanks for the link to the explorer that is actually very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this just be sure: There is no way to get a user id if the user in question did not authorize your App. So, the `reactions` and `likes` endpoint would just return an empty array, and the `comments` endpoint would just return data that is not specific for that user.

For example, the response for `reactions` of a Page Post that definitely has reactions and is public without any restrictions - the App being used even got "Page Public Content Access" approved:

```
{
  "data": [
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "...",
      "after": "..."
    },
    "next": "..."
  }
}
```

Comment: i see, so all the users that I want to see in the data array would have to authorize the app before their data could ever show up?

Comment: yup, exactly. this is for privacy reasons.

Comment: yeah i am going to try to crawl the fb page with a chrome extension

Comment: yeah I don't see how they could stop it...is it really bad to do that? I suppose they could block traffic from my chrome extension if they discovered it or something

Comment: it really does not matter if they could somehow detect it, if it´s not possible you should not do it. just my opinion, as a honest developer :) - and i would not be too sure, after all you would need to simulate some ajax calls in order to make this work correctly, it would be quite easy to detect if those are made automatically by a script or by a human. btw: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Facebook%20Jail

Comment: ha yeah I don't have an ethical problem with scraping facebook - you are only going to have access to what you should have access to, as long as you're not stealing someone else's data, which is not easy to do if you don't have the right token.

Answer (score 1):

I used to ask similar questions when trying to get information such as user id or user name of commenters on my fanpage using Graph API. To be able to obtain such information, your application needs to review Facebook's related rights. In my case I asked to review the following permissions: pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_metadata, pages_read_user_content and after being approved, you will get the information of the commenter